# Please how do I put link in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

My code needs to have a Link to another page. How do i get this to be resolved? I am trying to add hyperlinks so i can link up to another page,but the hyperlink does not show.

My code looks thus

```
import './Home.css'
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyLogin = () =>{
    return (
        <div align="center">
            <table width="61%" border="0">
            <div className="instagramlogo">
                <img src="images/43cc71bb1b43_2-removebg-preview.png"/>
            </div>
            <div className="login_page">
                <img border="0" align="center" src="images/images-removebg-preview.png" width="168" height="70" className="InstagramLogo" />
                <div className="usernameLogin">
                    <p align="center"><input type="text" name="T1" placeholder="  Phone number, username or email" size="33" className="inputBox" /></p>
                </div>
                <div className="usernameLogin">
                    <p align="center"><input type="password" name="T1" placeholder="  Password" size="33" className="inputBox" /></p>
                </div>
                <div className="usernameLogin">
                    <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="B1" class="BtnLoginClass"/></p>
                </div>
                <div className="forgotPassword">
                    <p align="center"><Link to="#"></Link><font face="Arial"/>Forgot Password?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div className="No_account">
                <p align="center"><Link to="/register"></Link><font face="Arial"/>No Account? Register</p>
                </div>
                <div className="get_app">
                    <p align="center"><font face="Arial"/> Get The app</p>
                </div>
                <div className="PlayStoreAppStoreArea">
                    <td width="204">
                    <p align="center">
                    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/appstore.png" width="169" height="51" align="right"/>
                    </p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="204">
                    <p align="center">
                    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/googlePlay.png" width="169" height="51" align="left"/>
                    </p>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyLogin;
```

What do i get to miss? What amI not doing correctly?

Comment: Can you show your AppRoutes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed your text outside of the Link component, change to

```
<Link to="#"><p>Forgot Password?</p></Link>
```

Comment: God bless you. Works fine . Thank you.